# Printing something 3 times in a row, and recording it?

Tags: java, if-statement, random, while-loop

This randomly prints heads or tails, and if heads is printed 3 times in a row, then I report that. Right now I have it so if 3 heads are printed total it reports it.Thanks.

```
public static void flip(Random r){
    int heads = 0; 
    int totalFlips = 0;
    Random number = new Random();
    int randomNumber;
    do {
        randomNumber = number.nextInt(2)+1;
        if(randomNumber == 1){
            System.out.println("heads");
            heads++;
            totalFlips++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("tails");
            totalFlips++;
        }
    } while(heads < 3);

    if(heads == 3){
        System.out.print("3 heads in a row after " +totalFlips + " flips");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Move `randomNumber = number.nextInt(2) + 1;` inside the `do-while` loop.

Comment: You generate a random number ( sometimes `1`, sometimes `2` ) and starting from the `do` line you have this value...

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the random number outside the loop so it will pick a 1 or a 2 and it won't change.  I suggest you move the random number generation inside your loop to generate a new number each time.

The reason it appears to only pick heads is that if it picks tails it will go into an infinite loop.

BTW Using a debugger would have found this bug faster.

Comment: I need it to print "3 heads in a row" if it's one after the other, and not just 3 heads total. How would I do that?

Comment: @MarinaClaire check `if (heads == totalFlips)` then it was all heads.

Comment: But what if it went tails heads heads heads then the 3 amount of heads don't equal the total flips which is 4.